# Converting to datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time data in a column and trying to figure out how can I get it in datetime format

```
2000
2100
2300
2355
0
1
5 
10
100
105
330
```

My question is how can I get these in datetime format:

output should be:

```
20:00:00
21:00:00
23:00:00
23:55:00
00:00:00
00:01:00
00:05:00
00:10:00
01:00:00
01:05:00
03:30:00
```

tried:

```
1. da =  pd.to_datetime(330, format='%H%M')
   output: '03:30:00'

2. d= str(datetime.timedelta(minutes = 55 ))
   output : '0:55:00'
```

But if I apply 1. to 100 it gives 10 hrs.

```
   eg: da =  pd.to_datetime(100, format='%H%M')
   output: '10:00:00'
```

Comment: Your question is getting three answers already! Nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format = '%H%M').dt.time


0     20:00:00
1     21:00:00
2     23:00:00
3     23:55:00
4     00:00:00
5     00:01:00
6     00:05:00
7     00:10:00
8     01:00:00
9     01:05:00
10    03:30:00
```

Comment: originally when I loaded the test data it was `dtype: int64` I was thinking on altering that as int64, but then I realized it is `to_datetime` needs a string. :)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `str.rjust`

```
pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str).str.rjust(4,'0'),format='%H%M').dt.time
Out[41]: 
0     20:00:00
1     21:00:00
2     23:00:00
3     23:55:00
4     00:00:00
5     00:01:00
6     00:05:00
7     00:10:00
8     01:00:00
9     01:05:00
10    03:30:00
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Comment: maybe `zfill` could be nice

Answer (score 0):

Since novice code, I am making the things more explicit and adding the formatting letters `%H` and `%M` info:

```
df['cname'] = pd.to_datetime(df['cname'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format = '%H%M').dt.time
print(df['cname'])

# %H    Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.   07
# %M    Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.     06
```